# Apache Ignite How to set the primary key to automatically grow?

Tags: ignite

Well, I have a requirement now that requires `Apache Ignite SQL`. When creating a table, it is similar to setting the primary key to grow automatically in `Mysql`. When the `Apache Ignite` creates the table, set the primary key to grow automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no autoincrement in Ignite SQL. But you can implement a custom SQL function, that generates IDs, based on [IgniteAtomicSequence](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/id-generator):

```java
public class SqlFunc {
    @QuerySqlFunction
    public static long nextId() {
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.ignite();
        IgniteAtomicSequence seq = ignite.atomicSequence("seq", 0, true);

        return seq.getAndIncrement();
    }
}
```

Here is cache a configuration, that allows to use `nextId()` function in SQL:

```xml
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
    <property name="name" value="cache"/>
    <property name="sqlFunctionClasses" value="com.example.SqlFunc"/>
    <property name="sqlSchema" value="PUBLIC"/>
</bean>
```

More on custom SQL functions: https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/custom-sql-functions

**UPD:**

Note, that every time `IgniteAtomicSequence` reserves a range of ids, an internal transaction is started. It may lead to unexpected consequences like deadlocks, if explicit transactions are used.

So, this approach should be used with care. In particular, SQL queries, that use the `nextId()` function, shouldn't be run within transactions.

Comment: I have a question now. Should I rebuild this method in the `Apache Ignite` project? Or should I create a new project to put this in the new project, if I put this method in the new method then Should jar` be placed in `libs` in the `Apache Ignite` installation directory? If I want to use this method when creating a table now, how do I use it?

Comment: The class, specified in `sqlFunctionClasses` property should be on class path of all nodes. You can put a jar with it to libs directory.

Comment: If I want to use the primary key to automatically grow this method when I create the table, how do I use it?

Comment: You should use it in insert statements and specify its result as a value of the primary key. For example, `INSERT INTO accounts(id, name) VALUES (nextId(), 'John')`

Comment: Thank you for your careful answer, I already know how to use it now.